# Objective-C Incompatible Block Type error

Tags: objective-c

I have this method:

```
- (void)shareItems:(NSArray *)shareItems fromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController anchorView:(UIView *)anchorView completion:(void (^)(NSString *activityType, BOOL, NSError *))completionHandler;
```

[image]

I'm simply trying to implement it in XCode 7.0.1 and I'm getting the following error messages:

If you can't see, I tried to implement:

```
[[VMSocialShareManager defaultManager] shareItems:shareItems fromViewController:self anchorView:shareCell completion:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed,  NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

But get the error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSString *__strong, BOOL, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(BOOL, NSString *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

OK, sure, I'll try to flip the `BOOL` and the `NSString` even though that makes no sense:

```
[[VMSocialShareManager defaultManager] shareItems:shareItems fromViewController:self anchorView:shareCell completion:^(BOOL completed, NSString *activityType, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

But then that gives the error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(BOOL, NSString *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSString *__strong, BOOL, NSError *__strong)'
```

Comment: But the question is: how is this method _actually declared in VMSocialShareManager_?

Comment: See also, as always http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/

Comment: @matt: The first line in the question is the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have names for the other two items in your block in your declaration. It should be:

```
- (void)shareItems:(NSArray *)shareItems 
fromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
        anchorView:(UIView *)anchorView 
        completion:(void (^)(NSString *name, BOOL flag, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

You are missing the `flag` and `error` parameter names.

Edit: to show that the order of the parameters really doesn't matter, I have created a test project with the above method signature in the `AppDelegate`, and called it in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. It runs as expected. I've attached the sample project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/264245142/Block%20Test.zip).

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to change the argument order when you actually call the method?

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out I just needed to put `activityType` in the middle, in between `success` and `error`. No idea why, but it compiles now:

```
- (void)shareItems:(NSArray *)shareItems fromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController anchorView:(UIView *)anchorView completion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString *activityType, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

Comment: What?! But that makes no sense! I just created a new project with activityType as first parameter. Works perfectly. I think something else must be at fault here! I've attached the sample project in my answer.

Comment: @Flying_Banana It definitely seems like some sort of bug. I cleaned the project multiple times to make sure that wasn't the issue. I think it had something to do with this, and changing the order just simply forced XCode to recompile.

Comment: Hmm, I guess irreproducible bugs come up sometimes :/ maybe the next time you update Xcode the bug will miraculously go away!